# How to create a heart shape button with rollover effect to replace add to facvorites in opencart theme

Tags: php, css, themes, e-commerce, opencart

We are trying to replace the add to favorites button with a heart shaed css button something like on FAB.com

The code the create a heart shape css is

this cs

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Creating Heart using CSS3 </title> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
      #heart { 
        position: relative; 
        width: 100px; 
        height: 90px; 
      } 

      #heart:before, #heart:after { 
        position: absolute; 
        content: ""; 
        left: 50px; 
        top: 0; 
        width: 50px; 
        height: 80px; 
        background: red; 
        border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0; 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
        transform: rotate(-45deg); 
       -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%; 
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%; 
       -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%; 
       -o-transform-origin: 0 100%; 
       transform-origin: 0 100%; 
     } 

      #heart:after { 
        left: 0; 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
       transform: rotate(45deg); 
       -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; 
       -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; 
       -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%; 
       -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%; 
       transform-origin :100% 100%; 
     } 
  </style> 
</head>
```

**HTML :**

```
<body> 
      <div id="heart"></div> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Now to make it possible where if the person has made it a favorite it stays red but without rollover its just a red border around the heart.

Comment: Why dont you use use an image? Or some kind of font such as [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) with the [2 states](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/heart-empty/)?

Comment: You can make the rollover but you need js to keep the state when clicked. Just use an image because you're making your life harder and it's not worth it. Also, bear in mind that the CSS you provided works only in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not css expert, but here's my idea:

use both:

```
.heart and .heartwhite
```

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nwznn/

But if you ask me, I Would stick to images